# Points group automatically when adding delimited text layer

Tags: qgis, point

I'm using QGIS 3.10. I am working with an Excel table with records having coordinates. I'm adding a delimited text layer, that is shown as points. However, records with the same coordinates are shown as a single point instead of several ones. Is there a way to separate them?

In the image, the selected point has 3 records for the same locality (LOCALIDADE at the right panel).

[image]

I tried to use Point Cluster and Point Displacement, but these two are not what I was expecting... the first one shows how many points are overlapping, while the other one I didn't quite understood. But what would work for me was if instead of one point, it was three points, one overlapping the other, so one could easily see that there is three records at the same locality.

Comment: They are three points, not one. In the Identify Results panel are being showed the three features. You can select each of them from the Attributes Table, each feature has a row and you can select just one row there. But since they have the same coordinates, the default behavior is that they overlap, and the three points are being identified.

Comment: I tried to use Point Cluster and Point Displacement, but these two are not what I was expecting... the first one groups the points and show how many are there, while the other one I didn't quite understood. But what would work for me was if instead of one point, it has three, one overlapping the other, so it was easily visualized. The closest I got from that (the visual thing) was using transparency on the points color.

Comment: The second option (point cluster) displayes a number showing the amount of overlapping points (by default (this can be changed)).

Comment: @MrXsquared, I did edit the question... thank you.

Comment: Can you explain or include a draft of how do you want to show the overlapped points?

Comment: So, talking to others, I discovered that what I wanted was possible with the tool "buffer". It showed exactly the overlapping points as I wanted, but visible only when zooming in the map. What worked for me, for now, was simply using a transparency on the symbol, so the points with more than one record are darker.